# Reduce dataset based on value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
dtf<-data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), value=c(2,4,6,8,4,6,8,10))
```

for every id the values are sorted with ascending order

i want to reduce the dtf to include only the first row for every `id` that the value exceeds a specified limit. Only one row per `id`, and that should be the one that the `value` first exceed a specified limit.

For this example and for the limit of `5` the dtf should reduce to :

```
A 6
B 6
```

Is the a nice way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done with `aggregate`:

```
dtf<-data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), value=c(2,4,6,8,4,6,8,10))

limit <- 5

aggregate(value ~ id, dtf, function(x) x[x > limit][1])
```

The result:

```
  id value
1  A     6
2  B     6
```

---

*Update*: A solution for multiple columns:

An example data frame, `dtf2`:

```
dtf2 <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
                   value=c(2,4,6,8,4,6,8,10),
                   col3 = letters[1:8],
                   col4 = 1:8)
```

A solution including `ave`:

```
with(dtf2, dtf2[ave(value, id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x > limit)) == 1, ])
```

The result:

```
  id value col3 col4
3  A     6    c    3
6  B     6    f    6
```

Comment: This solution does not depend on the order.  Nice.

Comment: This solution however deletes potential other variables in the dtf data frame.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, with your update, it might be better to consider something like `with(dtf2, dtf2[value == ave(value, id, FUN = function(x) min(x[x > 5])), ])` in case the value column is actually *not* ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "nice" option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dft, key = "id")

DT[value > 5, head(.SD, 1), by = key(DT)]
#    id value
# 1:  A     6
# 2:  B     6
```

And, in the spirit of sharing, an option using `sqldf` which might be nice depending on whether you feel more comfortable with SQL.

```
sqldf("select id, min(value) as value from dtf where value > 5 group by id")
#   id value
# 1  A     6
# 2  B     6
```

---

#### Update: Unordered source data, and a `data.frame` with multiple columns

Based on your comments to some of the answers, it seems like there might be a chance that your "value" column might not be ordered like it is in your example, and that there are other columns present in your `data.frame`.

Here are two alternatives for those scenarios, one with `data.table`, which I find easiest to read and is most likely the fastest, and one with a typical "split-apply-combine" approach that is commonly needed for such tasks.

First, some sample data:

```
dtf2 <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                   value = c(6,4,2,8,4,10,8,6),
                   col3 = letters[1:8],
                   col4 = 1:8)
dtf2 # Notice that the value column is not ordered
#   id value col3 col4
# 1  A     6    a    1
# 2  A     4    b    2
# 3  A     2    c    3
# 4  A     8    d    4
# 5  B     4    e    5
# 6  B    10    f    6
# 7  B     8    g    7
# 8  B     6    h    8
```

Second, the `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dtf2)
DT # Verify that the data are not ordered
#    id value col3 col4
# 1:  A     6    a    1
# 2:  A     4    b    2
# 3:  A     2    c    3
# 4:  A     8    d    4
# 5:  B     4    e    5
# 6:  B    10    f    6
# 7:  B     8    g    7
# 8:  B     6    h    8
DT[order(value)][value > 5, head(.SD, 1), by = "id"]
#    id value col3 col4
# 1:  A     6    a    1
# 2:  B     6    h    8
```

Second, base R's common "split-apply-combine" approach:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(dtf2, dtf2$id), 
               function(x) x[x$value > 5, ][which.min(x$value[x$value > 5]), ]))
#   id value col3 col4
# A  A     6    a    1
# B  B     6    h    8
```

Comment: +1 You don't need to set a key, btw. Ad hoc by is usually adequate and has the advantage that group order is maintained.

Comment: Does this solution depend on the dtf data.frame being sorted? This solution preserves potential other variables of the dtf data frame

Comment: @ECII, I believe it does. There are several ways around this. One is setting the key as `"id,value"` when creating your data table, then running `DT[value > 5, head(.SD, 1), by = "id"]`; another is to do something like `DT[order(id, value)][value > 5, head(.SD, 1), by = "id"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(value~id, dtf[dtf[,'value'] > 5,], min)
  id value
1  A     6
2  B     6
```

This does depend on the elements being sorted, as that will be the entry returned by `min`

Answer (score 2):

might aswell, an alternative with `plyr` and `head` :

```
library(plyr)
dtf<-data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), value=c(2,4,6,8,4,6,8,10))
limit <- 5
result <- ddply(dtf, "id", function(x) head(x[x$value > limit ,],1) )


    > result
  id value
1  A     6
2  B     6
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your data.frame being sorted:

```
threshold <- 5
foo <- dtf[dtf$value>=threshold,]
foo[c(1,which(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(foo$id)))>0)),]
```